# Aspect ratio 16/9 of child div always to fit parent div in CSS, not working on small height

Tags: html, css, aspect-ratio

I am trying to add a face overlay to an image, where I want the face to always be within the inner div.

The image needs to fit over a 16/9 ratio backdrop and always fit within the outer container, I have this working where the outside div is greater height than a 16/9 ratio, however whenever it drops below 16/9 it chops the bottom and top of the head off.

I need this to work with IOS so aspect-ratio does not work on safari, hence me using the old padding-top trick for 16/9.

Can anyone help me?

What I want is something like this...

[image]

But what i'm getting is this...

[image]

```css
.outside {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.inside {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  background: blue;
}

.img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<h1>Works when height is bigger</h1>

  <div class="outside" style="height:400px!important">
  <div class="inside" style="padding-top: 56.25%;">
    <img src="https://solvemoji-test.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/unnamed.jpg" class="img">
  </div>
</div>

<h1>Does not work when height is smaller</h1>

<div class="outside">
  <div class="inside" style="padding-top: 56.25%;">
    <img src="https://solvemoji-test.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/unnamed.jpg" class="img">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please could you add images to make your snippet work thanks (possibly the use of proxy is not working ) in the snippet system?)

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean, there are pictures in the question, which can you not see?

Comment: I can't see any - something to do with the proxy maybe?

Comment: Ahh i'm sorry I see the issue now, I just used an image from Google, i've updated this should work now.

Comment: Could you describe a bit more what you want to happen when the aspect ratio means it doesn't 'fit' - obviously you want the head to fit completely, but do you always want some red and/or blue showing? And/or do you want the white to be the same width in the two examples, but with the head to be shrunk to fit completely in the second example?

Comment: I want there to always be a blue 16:9 box, with a head inside.  Unless the outter div is exactly 16:9, there will be red either at the top and bottom, or red at the sides.  If you imagine that the blue area is a video, where I always want the 16:9 video shown.  I also want to overlay a head template onto the video.  My use case is that I want to overlay a head template over a webcam stream.  So I need the head to always be centered in the 16:9 video, or the blue area in my example above.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand, I had thought you needed the white-backed head image to always be full height. So I see now that the blue bit (with head) is either full width or full height but always 16/9 ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know the height of outer (as you do in the question) you can use the CSS min function to decide what the width and height of the inner element should be to ensure it has a 16/9 ratio.

This snippet removes the img element and replaces it with a background image to the inner element. The height of outer is passed as a CSS variable rather than as a height setting so that calculations can be done on it.

The results are:

[image]

```css
.outside {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: calc(var(--h) * 1px);
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inside {
  height: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  background-color: blue;
  --minw: calc(var(--h) * 16px / 9);
  width: min(100%, var(--minw));
  background-image: url(https://solvemoji-test.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/unnamed.jpg);
  background-size: auto min(100%, calc(var(--h) * 1px));
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<h1>Height is bigger</h1>

  <div class="outside" style="--h: 400">
  <div class="inside">
  </div>
</div>

<h1>Height is smaller</h1>

<div class="outside" style="--h: 200;">
  <div class="inside">
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that if the height of outer is not known in advance then I think you will have to resort to JS to set --h at run time.

Comment: Perfect thanks so much, this seems to be exactly what I am after, legend!

Answer (score 0):

You might not need absolute positioned image inside the absolute positioned div, for instance

```css
.outside {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}

.inside {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 72px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 72px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: blue;
}

.img {
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="outside">
  <div class="inside">
    <img class="img" src="https://solvemoji-test.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/unnamed.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works for when the parent is wider than 16/9 ratio but if you look at my original snippet I need the blue inner to always be 16/9 ratio.  So if you change it to say 4/3 on the outside the inside is not 16/9 still, in fact you don't see any blue at all in this case

Comment: I'm a bit lost. How can the blue inner have aspect ratio 16/9 if the outer's aspect ratio is less? (Nothing to do with how it's coded, but to do with the basic geometry of the situation).